# Returning mailitem property of item in inbox: Error 438 object doesn't support this property or method

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

I am trying to run the macro below in Excel.

I get

> error 438 object doesn't support this property or method

on the line `If OutlookMail.ReceivedTime >= Range("From_date").Value Then`

```
Option Explicit

Sub getDataFromOutlook()

    Dim OutlookApp As Outlook.Application
    Dim OutlookNamespace As Namespace
    Dim Folder As MAPIFolder
    Dim OutlookMail As Variant
    Dim objOwner As Outlook.Recipient
    Dim i As Integer

    Set OutlookApp = New Outlook.Application

    Set OutlookNamespace = OutlookApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")

    Set objOwner = OutlookNamespace.CreateRecipient("SharedMailboxaddres@companyname.com")
objOwner.Resolve

    If objOwner.Resolved Then
        Set Folder = OutlookNamespace.GetSharedDefaultFolder(objOwner, olFolderInbox)
    End If

    i = 1

    For Each OutlookMail In Folder.Items
        If OutlookMail.ReceivedTime >= Range("From_date").Value Then
            Range("eMail_sender").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.SenderName
            Range("eMail_subject").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.Subject
            Range("eMail_date").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.ReceivedTime
            Range("eMail_categories").Offset(i, 0).Value = OutlookMail.Categories
            Range("eMail_flag_status").Offset(i, 0) = OutlookMail.FlagStatus

            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next OutlookMail

    Set Folder = Nothing
    Set OutlookNamespace = Nothing
    Set OutlookApp = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: I suspect **From_date** is the name of your column (i.e. in row 1) and not the name of your range. Even if you have that as a name for your range, you haven't specified which sheet the range belongs too. `ActiveSheet` might not have that range which is what it's attempting to do with your current code

Comment: From_date is a cell defined in excel in which I have enter a specific date in order to get only the mails from that date from outlok

Answer (score 3):

An obvious fact is that Outlook folders may contain a different kind of items, so not every type provides the `ReceivedTime` property:

```
For Each OutlookMail In Folder.Items
    If OutlookMail.ReceivedTime >= Range("From_date").Value Then
```

You must check the item type first before accessing any property or method to make sure such a member exists for the item:

```
For Each OutlookMail In Folder.Items
   If TypeOf OutlookMail Is MailItem Then
      If OutlookMail.ReceivedTime >= Range("From_date").Value Then
```

Comment: so where do I put the "If TypeOf OutlookMail Is MailItem Then" in the macro?

Comment: @MaraBiz in the loop where you're iterating `Folder.Items`. Better yet, Rename that variable to `unknownItem`, and then declare an `outlookMailItem As Outlook.MailItem`, and when `TypeOf unknownItem Is Outlook.MailItem` then you can `Set outlookMailItem = unknownItem` and then from there all the member calls you make against `outlookMailItem` will be validated at compile-time, and then error 438 isn't going to happen (you'll get a compiler error instead of a run-time error, if you misspell a member name).

Comment: @MaraBiz I have corrected the answer to show a possible place.

Comment: Please accept the answer if it helped to resolve your query as this will close the query

Answer (score 1):

Error 438 means you're trying to invoke a member that does not exist - that can only ever happen at run-time, against late-bound code.

> **Late bound?** VBA can't know what the actual type of a `Variant` or `Object` is going to be until the code is actually running - when members are bound at run-time, it's called *late binding*. When members are bound at compile-time, it's called *early binding*. You want as much of your code to be early-bound, so that you pick up such errors at compile-time rather than at run-time.

But you're referencing the `Outlook` library - you have no valid reason to late-bind anything here.

`Folder.Items` contains many object types: the `OutlookMail` variable has a very misleading name:

```
For Each OutlookMail In Folder.Items
```

A better name could be `folderItem`, or `unknownItem` - because we know it's something that's in a folder, but we don't know what type of object that is. All we know of it, is that it's an `Object`:

```
Dim unknownItem As Object
For Each unknownItem In Folder.Items
```

Now if the type of `unknkownItem` is `Outlook.MailItem`, we can *cast* it to that interface:

```
    Dim emailItem As Outlook.MailItem
    If TypeOf unknownItem Is Outlook.MailItem Then
        Set emailItem = unknownItem
```

And now every single member call we make against `emailItem` will be validated at compile-time instead of run-time, because we *know* that inside this conditional block, we're looking at a `MailItem` object.

```
        Sheet1.Range("eMail_sender").Offset(i, 0).Value = emailItem.SenderName
```

Note that `SenderName` will be in the names list when you type the `.` dot: that's how you know you're making an early-bound member call.

Avoid implicit late binding wherever you can - that means working with object variables that have an explicit, declared type, and avoiding member calls against `Variant` and `Object`.